# When transferring data from my Android phone to my Microsoft Windows computer, why are there large disk space variations?

Tags: windows-7, android, file-transfer

I am transferring data (photos and videos) from my Android phone to my Microsoft Windows computer. Each file is between 2 MB and ~30MB. I see large disk space variations: in my case, when I look at the remaining space it oscillates between 1.43GB and 1.95 GB, seemingly 1 oscillation for each file transfer. Why are these such large oscillations?

Example:

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate my computer and Android 6 on my phone (LG 4).

Comment: Windows file transfer statistics seem to be a vague suggestion rather than accurate data. Remaining time for file transfer varies even more wildly, going *up* as well as down.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The gif in the question doesn't show up the Windows file transfer statistics, but the remaining space in the destination disk as indicated in Windows Explorer.